# DTAttributedTextView does not relayout

Tags: ios, swift, dtcoretext

When the DTAttributedTextView's frame changes the content (text) inside the view is not relayouted. I have the text view in my tableView cell and its height is specified by a layout constraint, which value I change in code. Width changes automatically with the constraints based on the cell width.

I have tried to manually call `setNeedsLayout`, `layoutIfNeeded`, `relayoutText`, `setNeedsDisplay`. Nothing seems to help. Why is the content layout locked this way?

This seems to work for the height, but not for the width:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    comment.attributedTextContentView.layoutFrame = DTCoreTextLayoutFrame(
        frame: comment.frame,
        layouter: comment.attributedTextContentView.layouter)
    comment.relayoutText()
}
```

Comment: For now just replaced DTAttributesTextView with UITextView. Works fine when using DTUseiOS6Attributes option with DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Its necessary to set the layouter to nil before calling relayoutText

```
comment.attributedTextContentView.layoutFrame = DTCoreTextLayoutFrame(
    frame: comment.frame,
    layouter: comment.attributedTextContentView.layouter)
//gets rid of cached layouter
comment.layouter = nil
comment.relayoutText()
```